# Heat loss - hot spots on roof

Tags: leak, roof

I purchased a house this summer and am noticing some hot spots on the roof. The old home owner just said they kept the roof shoveled to prevent it from causing ice dams. That is fine and all - but was wondering if any of you might have suggestions on what might be causing it. Seems strange that it is localized directly over a soffit vent. Any ideas? Attached is a picture. Seems like it must be a pretty severe heat loss... But I really have no experience. There is blown in insulation in the attic. 
[image: Snow melts][image: 20 degrees out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All homes have variation in heat loss. Yours seems to correspond with the soffit vents. It could just be that the additional airflow in that area leads to more melting in marginally cold weather. It doesn't take much heat to melt snow on a 35 degree day.

It could also be that there's another vent directed through the soffit vent. It's all guesswork until you inspect the attic, but I see no reason to be alarmed.

Comment: Yeah - there is just minor damage from a past leak and I suspect that is the culprit. I'll go check out the attic and just keep the roof cleaned off so it doesn't dam up.

Comment: The pic attached above was on a 20 degree day.

Comment: As it turns out - there was an old microwave vent with no insulation on the duct work. You were right! Insulated over the duct and no more melt